# TextEditor disable editing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

#### Overview:

- I have a TextEditor that uses a binding to a constant, so that value can't change.

#### Aim:

- I would like the text editor not to show the keyboard however still allow the user to copy text.

#### Question:

- How to achieve copying of text but without showing the keyboard?
- I would prefer to do in SwiftUI or is it only possible using `UIViewRepresentable`?

#### Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: View {
    
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: .constant(text))
    }
}

struct TextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        let text = "this is some text"
        
        TextView(text: text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is using "textSelection" modifly

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .textSelection(.enabled)
    .padding()
```

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 15**

```
yourField
  .textSelection(.enabled)
```

**iOS 14 and Lower**

I don't think there's great swiftui support for this right now, considering it's a constant, I might just manually add the copy behavior:

```
struct CopyableLabel : View {
    let text: String = "here's a constant"

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    UIPasteboard.general.string = text
                }) {
                    Text("Copy")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If you want the user to be able to manually select portions, I think the most efficient way would be to drop to uikit, or roll something more complex

Comment: I think that's a great idea, actually copying is all I need. I never thought of `contextMenu`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I wrapped the Text inside a ScrollView to make it scrollable.

Comment: nice! I wish we could edit the context to appear like the standard black controls, but I think this is the new wave so maybe good for users to adapt.. glad it worked :)

Comment: I think context menu is used more as a way to provide secondary options to a normal button, hence the size and appearance. I think it like the equivalent (in functionality) to the right click on the Mac. I don't think something like UIMenuController exists in SwiftUI.